# iPhone 6 stuck in iTunes recovery logo

Tags: iphone, recovery

After having a jailbroken iPhone for a while, I wanted a clean version of iOS 9.3.1. So i followed all the steps in iTunes to achieve this. But when the little black bar on the iPhone was filled up it restarted into the iTunes recovery logo.

I tried every possible way of getting out of it, including trying DFU mode. But every single time I try something new it puts me back on the iTunes recovery logo.

What I have tried:

- Updating phone
- Restoring phone
- Trying another computer
- iRecovery

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried this but you didn't mention it so I thought I'd ask, do you have a pre-jailbreak backup you can put back on?

Comment: it wont let me do that unfortunately. I did some more research and the problem is most likely some jailbreak files still on my phone that apple cant delete. maybe if there was a software to open up the IOS directory while in recovery mode

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes a battery change will solve the problem

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  A couple things... single line answers are not a good fit for Ask Different.  We want more comprehensive answers; and if you have sources and or links to other resources, you should include those.  As such, I am recommending deletion of this post unless you can expand further.  Secondly, *how exactly does changing a battery solve a boot problem?*